# PHP read first item in object array

Tags: php, gocardless

I have my code in PHP which is returning this Array of data:

```
GoCardlessPro\Core\ListResponse Object
(
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => GoCardlessPro\Resources\Mandate Object
                (
                    [model_name:protected] => Mandate
                    [created_at:protected] => 2017-04-01T16:49:09.642Z
                    [id:protected] => ID001
                    [links:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [customer_bank_account] => CB001
                            [creditor] => CR001
                            [customer] => CU001
                        )

                    [metadata:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                    [next_possible_charge_date:protected] => 2017-04-06
                    [payments_require_approval:protected] => 
                    [reference:protected] => RE001
                    [scheme:protected] => bacs
                    [status:protected] => active
                    [data:GoCardlessPro\Resources\BaseResource:private] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 123
                            [created_at] => 2017-04-01T16:49:09.642Z
                            [reference] => RE001
                            [status] => active
                            [scheme] => bacs
                            [next_possible_charge_date] => 2017-04-06
                            [payments_require_approval] => 
                            [metadata] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                            [links] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [customer_bank_account] => 001
                                    [creditor] => CR001
                                    [customer] => CU001
                                )

                        )

                    [api_response] => 
                )

        )
)
```

I want to be able to read the ID of the first item in the`records` array.

This data is contained inside a variable called `$GC_Mandate;`

I have tried these:

```
echo $GC_Mandate->records->{0}->id;

echo $GC_Mandate->records->0->id;

echo $GC_Mandate->records->[0]->id;

$GC_Mandate = $GC_Mandate->records;
echo $GC_Mandate->{0}->id;
```

But none will return the data

Answer (score 1):

To get the first record, the syntax you need is `$GC_Mandate->records[ 0 ]`.

However, that object is a `GoCardlessPro\Resources\Mandate` object and its member `id` is protected<sup>1</sup>, so we'd need to know the interface of `GoCardlessPro\Resources\Mandate` (its public methods<sup>1</sup>), to know if we can somehow retrieve the value of `id`.

My guess would be `getId()`, so the full syntax would become

```
$GC_Mandate->records[ 0 ]->getId()
```

But, that's just a guess. You'd have to look into the documentation/class definition of `GoCardlessPro\Resources\Mandate`, to be sure if you can retrieve `id`.

---

[Turns out](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-pro-php/blob/master/lib/Resources/BaseResource.php) (provided I'm linking to the correct github repository) you can do:

```
$GC_Mandate->records[ 0 ]->id
```

since `GoCardlessPro\Resources\Mandate` extends `GoCardlessPro\Resources\BaseResource`, which exposes the protected members through `GoCardlessPro\Resources\BaseResource::__get()`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1. [visibility in PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

2. [magic methods in PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)</sup>

Comment: just tried your second option but thats not showing the value

Comment: @charlie Then I'm afraid you might have to look a little further into their documentation. Meanwhile, I've also tagged your question with [tag:gocardless]. Perhaps that garners the appropriate attention to you question.

Comment: @charlie Also, have you enabled the [reporting of errors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on your development server? Look into the errors log (or display them directly with `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, while on the development server (don't enable displaying of errors on a live server though)). That should give you more clues about what's going on.

Comment: i can loop through `$GC_Mandate->records` and echo the `ID` - not sure if that helps with trying to get the first item directly or should i just loop once and then break the loop?

Comment: @charlie If you can loop and access the `id` (or is it `ID`? Case is important here, as variables are case-sensitive), then `$GC_Mandate->records[ 0 ]->id` (or `->ID`) should also work, provided all the information (the array dump, array indexes, case-sensitivity, etc.) you posted so far is accurate. Please update your question with the exact (case-sensitive, etc) relevant code of your loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I guess I'll have to post.

You should try to `print_r($GC_Mandate);` and see what it gives out and then go from there.

Comment: Thats how I am retrieving the array in my question

Answer (score 0):

Try `$GC_Mandate->records[0]->__get('id')`

Answer (score 0):

it will return all data ..for perticulat data put this in foreach loop

```
 print_r($GC_Mandate['records']);
```